# How to flip and save Image

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, flip, imageicon

My Image declaration:

```
ImageIcon imageIcon1 = new ImageIcon(main.class.getResource("image1.png"));
Image image1 = imageIcon1.getImage();
```

How do I take image1, flip it along it's vertical axis and save it as another image?

I have googled and every solution I have found has come with some type of casting error.
Also, if there is a more efficient way to declare my image please let me know.

Comment: "every solution I have found has come with some type of casting error" - What were these solutions (code) and what exactly were the errors (message/stacktrace)?

Comment: Why are you asking the [same question twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983099/how-do-you-flip-an-image-and-also-change-its-location)? and also providing not enough information to allow a good answer in either? This unnecessary division of the discussion is not fair to the volunteers on this site and is not appreciated here.

Comment: What the hell :/ You want to get deleted? That's awkward!

Comment: If you want to delete your account, please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account.

Answer (score 8):

You state:

> I have googled and every solution I have found has come with some type of casting error.

Which only tells us that you're doing something wrong but doesn't tell us what, limiting how we can help you. I can only tell you some steps that have worked for me:

- Create another BufferedImage the same size as the first,
- get its Graphics2D context via `createGraphics()`,
- flip the graphics via an `AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(-1, 1)` for a horizontal flip
- Don't forget to then translate the transform to bring the flipped image to where you want it.
- draw the old image into the new image,
- dispose the Graphics2D object.

If you need more help, then please show us what you've tried and include any and all error messages.

For instance, I played with this when playing with mirror sprite images a while back. Compile and run this to see what I mean:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FlipViaTransform {
   private static final String SPRITE_SHEET_SPEC = "http://www.funorb.com/img/images/game/"
         + "central/dev_diary/sprite_sheet_full.gif";
   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 200;
   private static final int SPRITE_ROWS = 8; // an 8 x 8 sprite sheet

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         URL spriteSheetUrl = new URL(SPRITE_SHEET_SPEC);
         BufferedImage spriteSheet = ImageIO.read(spriteSheetUrl);
         final ImageIcon[] iconsA = new ImageIcon[64];
         final ImageIcon[] iconsB = new ImageIcon[64];
         double wD = (double) spriteSheet.getWidth() / SPRITE_ROWS;
         double hD = (double) spriteSheet.getHeight() / SPRITE_ROWS;
         int w = (int) wD;
         int h = (int) hD;

         // *** here's what I used to flip
         AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(-1, 1); // *** flip
         at.translate(-wD, 0);  // *** translate so that flipped image is visible
         for (int i = 0; i < SPRITE_ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SPRITE_ROWS; j++) {
               int x = (int) (i * wD);
               int y = (int) (j * hD);
               BufferedImage imgA = spriteSheet.getSubimage(x, y, w, h);
               BufferedImage imgB = new BufferedImage(imgA.getWidth(),
                     imgA.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
               Graphics2D g2 = imgB.createGraphics();
               g2.setTransform(at);   // *** transform
               g2.drawImage(imgA, 0, 0, null);  // *** draw old image into new
               g2.dispose();  // *** get rid of graphics2d object

               iconsA[j * SPRITE_ROWS + i] = new ImageIcon(imgA);
               iconsB[j * SPRITE_ROWS + i] = new ImageIcon(imgB);
            }
         }

         final JLabel labelA = new JLabel("Image");
         final JLabel labelB = new JLabel("Mirror Image");

         labelA.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
         labelB.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
         labelA.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
         labelB.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
         labelA.setIcon(iconsA[0]);
         labelB.setIcon(iconsB[0]);
         final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
         panel.add(labelA);
         panel.add(labelB);
         Timer spriteTimer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {
            int spriteIndex = 0;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
               labelA.setIcon(iconsA[spriteIndex]);
               labelB.setIcon(iconsB[spriteIndex]);
               spriteIndex++;
               spriteIndex %= iconsA.length;
            }
         });
         spriteTimer.start();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel, "AffineTransform Example", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
         spriteTimer.stop();
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

which displays as:
[image]

Comment: @CalinGribble: you would save it same as you would *any* image. `ImageIO.write(...)`. Please do check the ImageIO API as it will show you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this, but you can try to research if you can use a 3d party library such as ImageMagick or GraphicsMagic with Java.  Those libraries can read PNG images and perform graphics operation on them.

Comment: There is no need for this as a simple flip can be done with ease with just core Java.